# NumPy - Getting minimum value per row and maintaining shape

Tags: python, numpy

Say I have an array with shape `(N, 5, 2)`. I would like to get a the minimum value along one axis.

To do this, I've done the following:

```
np.min(arr[:, :, 0], axis=1)
```

However, this returns with shape `(N,)` when I would like `(N, 1)`; that can be accomplished with:

```
np.min(arr[:, :, 0], axis=1).reshape(arr.shape[0], 1)
```

That however seems quite verbose and leaves me wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: @Divakar I don't follow

Comment: Sorry, I meant `np.min(arr[:, :, [0]], axis=1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct an array with an extra axis by using:

```
x[...,None]
```

Then we can thus calculate the minimum over the second axis:

```
x[...,None].min(axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use a slice, and it gets returned as shape `(N, 1)`

```
>>> np.min(x[:, :, 0:1], axis = 1).shape

#or

>>> np.min(x[...,0:1], axis = 1)
```